# test.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC5Ev]+0x8)||undefined reference to `vtable for A'|

Tags: c++

I have a veeeery simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
    public :

            A(){}
            virtual void fun(std::string);
            virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A
{
    public :

            B(){}
            void fun(std::string);
            ~B(){};
};

void B::fun(std::string)
{

}

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

And I got this messages trying to compile it:

> /home/Temp/test.o||In function `A::A()':|
>   test.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC5Ev]+0x8)||undefined reference to`
>   vtable for A'| /home/Temp/test.o||In function `A::~A()':|
>   test.cpp:(.text._ZN1AD2Ev[_ZN1AD5Ev]+0xb)||undefined reference to`
>   vtable for A'| /home/Temp/test.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[typeinfo for
>   B]+0x8)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'| ||=== Build
>   finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Why is that?

Comment: Google the error. This is _well covered_ on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either implement `A::fun` or indicate it as pure virtual using `= 0`:

```
virtual void fun(std::string) = 0;
```

Still keep in mind that if `fun` is pure virtual you will not be able to instantiate `A` in main.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to implement `A::fun`.

If you don't want to implement a virtual function, mark it as pure with `= 0`, but note that the class will become abstract and you won't be able to instantiate it.

Comment: Huh, thanks, that was it:) My problem is that I dont want to declare `fun` as abstract because I want to have `A` objects in my program. However, I dont need to implement a `fun` in `A` ...

Comment: @yak: Then you are trying to make something that is both an interface _and_ a class. Simply don't do that -- it's a broken design.